# How to suppress multiple plots popup in spyder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I have `multiple plt.show()` and if I run the script from geany etc, the 2nd plot will not show until I close the first plot. However, in Spyder it will automatically show all the plots.

How can I let Spyder only show one plot and move to 2nd plot after I close the first plot?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I think you need to go to the menu `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics` and deactivate the option called `Activate support`. That should give you the same behavior as the one you have in a regular console.

Comment: Hi martineau, sorry it didn't work!  now there is not even a plot showing up. Here is my code, for example, I have 5 functions and each function plot one graph. Inside each function, I have final few lines like this:   plt.show()
    plt.close()
    plt.clf()